# Signed measure and bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Definition: (Total variation norm)
>
> Suppose $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$.
>
> For all partition $\Pi = \{a = t_0 < t_1 <\cdots <t_N=b\} $ of $[a,b]$, denote $V_\Pi(f):=\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} |f(t_{j+1} - f(t_j)|$
>
> Denote $|f|_{TV} := \sup\{V_\Pi (f) :  \Pi$ partition$\}$

Consider $\nu: \mathcal{B}[a,b] \to (-\infty,\infty)$ a finite signed measure. By Hahn-Jordan decomposition, there are $\nu^+,\nu^-: \mathcal{B}[a,b]\to [0,\infty)$ such that $\nu = \nu^+ -\nu^- $

Consider $\rho: X\to \mathbb{R}$  such that $t\mapsto \nu[a,t]$

Prove that

$$|\rho|_{TV}=|\nu|$$

---

My attempt:

Given $\Pi=\{a = t_0<\cdots < t_N= b\}$,

$$
V_\Pi(\rho) = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} |\rho(t_{j+1}) - \rho(t_j)|$$

We have by definition $|\rho(t_{j+1}) - \rho(t_j)|  = |v[t_j, t_{j+1}]| $, so by triangle inequality,

$$V_\Pi (\rho) \leq \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} (\nu^+[t_j, t_{j+1}]+\nu^-[t_j, t_{j+1}]) = \nu^+ [a,b] + \nu^- [a,b] = |\nu|$$

So indeed we have $|\rho|_{TV} \leq |\nu|$. My trouble is with the other inequality.

Comment: The claim is wrong. Take $\nu^+=\nu^-.$ Then $\nu= 0$ and $\rho=0.$ . In order to get the claimed equality the measures $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ should be singular at each other.

Comment: You're right. Now I fixed the statement, and assumed that $\nu$ is a finite signed measure (the Hahn decomposition ensures that $\nu^+ $, $\nu^- $ are singular at each other)

Comment: Let $\Omega_+\cup \Omega_-=\mathcal{B}([a,b])$ be a Hahn-decomposition with disjoint $\Omega_+,\Omega_-$. Can you now construct a partition of any subset of $\mathcal{B}([a,b])$ such that you get equality instead of an inequality?